# CSS width different for button and div elements

Tags: css, width

I'm trying to figure out what it is about the **button** element that causes the CSS **width** attribute to be treated as the button's entire width, including the padding and border widths. CSS generally has **width** defining the content width, the width of the box inside the padding, and the browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome on Windows 7, at least) abide by that for **div**s.

In my example below, I style a **button** and a **div** to look alike (and with a hover effect) but, for the **div**, I use **width** to specify the width of the content area alone. So even though the two buttons occupy the same width overall, the CSS width for the **button** is 190px while the CSS width is 152px (or 150px on hover).

(The result is the same with or without the **display: inline-block** that I added to the CSS for the **div** to try to match the browser's **display** property for the **button**.)

The result:

[image]

Any insights?

```
<html>
    <style>
        .xbutton {
            width: 190px;
            text-align: left;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eaf2f5, #e0eaee); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(#eaf2f5, #e0eaee); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(#eaf2f5, #e0eaee); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
            background: linear-gradient(#eaf2f5, #e0eaee); /* Standard syntax */
            border: 1px solid #88949a;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 8px 18px 8px 18px;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #000000;
        }

        .xbutton:hover {
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#d2e0e8, #b8c3c9); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(#d2e0e8, #b8c3c9); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(#d2e0e8, #b8c3c9); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
            background: linear-gradient(#d2e0e8, #b8c3c9); /* Standard syntax */
            border: 2px solid #7b888e;
            padding: 8px 16px 8px 20px;
        }

        .xbutton-icon {
            margin: 0 7px 0 0;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        div.xbutton { display: inline-block; width: 152px; }
        div.xbutton:hover { width: 150px; }
     </style>


    <title>Button test</title>
    <div><button class="xbutton"><img class="xbutton-icon" src="GetFileAttachment.png" width="25" height="18">Email attachment</button></div>
    <div class="xbutton"><img class="xbutton-icon" src="GetFileAttachment.png" width="25" height="18">Email attachment</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a read about the box-sizing property, it might help you out here

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Browsers differ in how they display form elements. I see what you're seeing in firefox, but in other browsers, like Chrome and Safari, the to elements look the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to reset button css style which is defined by default in a different way for each browser.

```
/*fix for Firefox */
button::-moz-focus-inner{
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*reset button CSS */
button{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

#### Snippet:

```css
/*fix for Firefox */

button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*reset button CSS */

button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.xbutton {
  width: 190px;
  text-align: left;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eaf2f5, #e0eaee);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#eaf2f5, #e0eaee);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#eaf2f5, #e0eaee);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#eaf2f5, #e0eaee);
  /* Standard syntax */
  border: 1px solid #88949a;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 18px 8px 18px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000000;
}
.xbutton:hover {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#d2e0e8, #b8c3c9);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#d2e0e8, #b8c3c9);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#d2e0e8, #b8c3c9);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#d2e0e8, #b8c3c9);
  /* Standard syntax */
  border: 2px solid #7b888e;
  padding: 8px 16px 8px 20px;
}
.xbutton-icon {
  margin: 0 7px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div.xbutton {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 152px;
}
div.xbutton:hover {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<title>Button test</title>
<div>
  <button class="xbutton">
    <img class="xbutton-icon" src="http://lorempixel.com/25/18" width="25" height="18">Email attachment</button>
</div>
<div class="xbutton">
  <img class="xbutton-icon" src="http://lorempixel.com/25/18" width="25" height="18">Email attachment</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that feature. Done.